# Transmitting periodic message over TCP instead of UDP

Tags: tcp, udp

I have multiple sensors transmitting periodic readings to a server over internet. The frequency of transmission is 100ms. The message size will vary from 1KB to 12KB. I wants to keep the packet loss less than 5%. I read that the safer size for UDP datagram is 512B when transmitted over internet. Personally i did experience packet loss more than 10% when datagram of size 12KB were used. One solution would be to split the message and send it number of smaller message. But it is a huge overhead. Can i use TCP in this case instead of UDP? Is there any problems to take care while using TCP for periodic messages?

Comment: Did you do any research? TCP has no "messages", and in TCP everything must be delivered.

Comment: @CodeCaster I couldn't able to get you. Could you explain ?